# Mysql select with multiple total columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `sales` with 5 fields:

- `id`
- `date`
- `id_store`
- `id_customer`
- `price`

The table `customers`:

- `customers.id`
- `customers.name`

And the table `stores`:

- `stores.id`
- `stores.name`

I want to get this result:

```
January, Total customer name1, Total customer name2 ..., Total store name 1, Total store name 2...
February, Total customer name1, Total customer name2 ..., Total store name 1, Total store name 2...
March, Total customer name1, Total customer name2 ..., Total store name 1, Total store name 2...
April...
```

is it possible?

Comment: When you say "total customer name1", do you mean "total sales price of the customer name1"? If yes, you could use the "GROUP BY" statement mixed with the option "SUM".

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, using [`JOIN`s](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) and [`WITH ROLLUP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html). Basically, you'll `JOIN` your tables together to get the data rows you need, then `GROUP BY` multiple columns (in your case, probably `GROUP BY MONTH(sales.date), stores.id, customers.id WITH ROLLUP`). Grouping by multiple columns gives you nested groups, in the order the columns are listed. `WITH ROLLUP` will give you summary data for each nesting level; so in my example, you'd get totals per customer per store per month, and totals per store per month, and overall totals per month.

Comment: But show a column with total for each customer and each store?

Comment: It will show totals for each customer by store & month, and for each store by month. If you want independent totals for each, you'll have to run independent queries.